# Raspberry PI 2 termal printer not printing correctly

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have the Raspberry Pi 2 and the thermal printer SP-MP-E3. When I'm connecting the printer's RX pin to raspberry's TX pin the printer printing continuously something in Cheneese characters. Here is the image

[image: thermal printer error image]

I disabled the serial interface from the raspberry but when I'm connecting the pin I have the same problem

Extra info :
I'm trying to use the port ttyAMA0 ( serial port for TX ) with JSSC library
I'm trying to use the ESC/POS
I changed the mod on raspbian for the serial port with the command "sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0"
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the exists. When we connect a device to GPOS raspberry sendin signal for communication for this device. When it is a printer then printning continiously. The solution is to disable the serial interface
Here is the steps on rasbian
1 - Open terminal
2 - Write "sudo raspi-config" and press enter
3 - Go to advanced settings
4 - Disable the serial interface
5 - Restart rasbian